# gevent StreamServer.start() does not seem to do what I expect

Tags: python, networking, concurrency, gevent

I'm trying to wrap my brain around the concepts that [gevent](http://www.gevent.org) employs. Here's an example from the gevent code repository. It's a simple echo server.

```
from gevent.server import StreamServer

# this handler will be run for each incoming connection in a dedicated greenlet
def echo(socket, address):
    print ('New connection from %s:%s' % address)
    socket.sendall('Welcome to the echo server! Type quit to exit.\r\n')
    # using a makefile because we want to use readline()
    fileobj = socket.makefile()
    while True:
        line = fileobj.readline()
        if not line:
            print ("client disconnected")
            break
        if line.strip().lower() == 'quit':
            print ("client quit")
            break
        fileobj.write(line)
        fileobj.flush()
        print ("echoed %r" % line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # to make the server use SSL, pass certfile and keyfile arguments to the constructor
    server = StreamServer(('0.0.0.0', 6000), echo)
    # to start the server asynchronously, use its start() method;
    # we use blocking serve_forever() here because we have no other jobs
    print ('Starting echo server on port 6000')
    server.serve_forever()
```

That seems quite straightforward and I it works. However as it says in the comment that `serve_forever()` is a blocking function. If I change the last line to `server.start()` the program will stop after executing each line once. I am doing something wrong but the documentation is not very helpful.

In the documentation section [implementing servers with gevent](http://www.gevent.org/servers.html), it says that using `start()` should spawn a new greenlet for each new connection when using the following code:

```
 def handle(socket, address):
     print 'new connection!'

 server = StreamServer(('127.0.0.1', 1234), handle) # creates a new server
 server.start() # start accepting new connections
```

And then right after it says that `The server_forever() method calls start() and then waits until interrupted or until the server is stopped.` How am I supposed to run the server using `start()` so that it actually remains alive to catch the first connection?

Also:

1. What is the difference between `start()` and `serve_forever()`?
2. In what contexts should I choose one over the other?
3. Are calls to `gevent.spawn()` and `gevent.joinall()` necessary when using the first method, but somehow so obvious that they've been left out of the StreamServer-documentation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. start() is an asynchronous function that puts a server in a listening mode. It does not prevent your program from exiting though, which is your responsibility.
2. in simple cases you can use serve_forever(). start() becomes useful when you need to start multiple servers or do something else in addition to starting a server.
3. no, gevent.spawn() and gevent.joinall() have nothing to do with servers.

With [gevent 1.0](https://github.com/surfly/gevent/downloads) it's actually best to use gevent.wait() which blocks until there are no more active connections/greenlets/listeners/watchers.

Here's an example: https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/master/examples/portforwarder.py

Comment: will gevent 1.0 be avail for pip soon? i'd rather not build it manually

Comment: gevent.run() is now known as gevent.wait().